# Completely remove user while using chroot from Ubuntu RPi image

Tags: raspberrypi, user-management

I'm customizing Ubuntu for my project but every time I use `chroot` for deleting user and creating mine, I end up with two users <my_user> and <ubuntu>. Ubuntu is the default user for `Ubuntu Server 20.04.1 for Raspberry Pi`

I have tried the following commands but no result:

```
deluser --remove-home ubuntu
groupdel ubuntu
userdel -r ubuntu
rm -rf /home/ubuntu/
```

I assume that there is something inside system startup/flashing files creating this user but I can't find that.

System before install doesn't contain `/home/ubuntu` but after installation there is.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found out.

The answer is file `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg` there you can configure default user/groups/etc.

Best